# Turning any single-argument function into a generator function?

Tags: python, function, generator, yield

In [David Beazley's talk on generators](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf), he shows how to create a generator function from any single-argument function thus:

```
def generate(func):
    def gen_func(s):
        for item in s:
            yield func(item)
    return gen_func
```

and illustrates it with `math.sqrt`:

```
gen_sqrt = generate(math.sqrt)
for x in gen_sqrt(xrange(100)):
    print x
```

So why does:

```
gen_sum = generate(sum)
for x in gen_sum([1,2,3,4,5]):
    print x
```

produce:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-ef521f2bbfc8> in <module>()
      1 gen_sum = generate(sum)
----> 2 for x in gen_sum(1):
      3     print x

<ipython-input-50-3c0ba12c2429> in gen_func(s)
      1 def generate(func):
      2     def gen_func(s): # closure
----> 3         for item in s:
      4             yield func(item)
      5     return gen_func

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Is it more accurate to say that the function being a single-argument function is a necessary but insufficient condition for this approach to work? And that the other necessary condition is that the single argument must be a *single item* (and not a sequence)?

Comment: a sum takes two arguments ... the function has to be one that takes only one argument ... what do you expect the above to actually do? `math.sqrt(25)` vs `sum(25)` I think it becomes clear what the issue is ..

Comment: The exception you show the traceback of seems to be coming from a different call to `gen_sum` than the one you show above (which will also raise a `TypeError` with the same message, but at a different part of the code and for a different reason).

Comment: It must be a single-argument function **that accepts the kind of values *you're passing!*** `gen_sum([(1, 2), (3, 4, 5)])` would be fine, for example.

Comment: @Blckknght well-spotted. Same error though, ultimately.

Comment: @JoranBeasley `sum` takes a single argument. In my case above, that single argument is a list.

Comment: @Pyderman no, because you're *iterating over that list* to give the single arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a list whose elements are the wrong type. Of course it's not going to work, for the same reason that `gen_sqrt(['a', 's', 'd', 'f'])` wouldn't have worked.

You need to pass `gen_sum` a list of things it makes sense to call `sum` on, such as other lists:

```
for x in gen_sum([[1, 2], [3, 4]]):
    print x
```

Output:

```
3
7
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, both are necessary requirements:

```
def generate(func):
    def gen_func(s):
        for item in s:          # <--- requires s to be interable
            yield func(item)    # <--- requires func to accept a single argument
    return gen_func
```

So in

```
gen_sum = generate(func)
for x in gen_sum(s):
    print x
```

`func` must accept a single argument and `s` must be iterable.

Answer (score 1):

`generate` is the generator version of `map`.

```
map(lambda x: x*2, range(5))   [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

It takes the input range and applies the function the each of the element in the range.

`generate` does the same, but it doesn't return a list. It yields the result of each transformation.

Now take a look at your example. What would be the first result? `sum(1)`.

But `sum` expects a list, not an integer, hence the error message.